# Angular 9 - HttpInterceptor - Cannot read property length of null

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I use Angular 9 and HttpInterceptor like this:

```
export class AppHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      ...
      return next.handle(authReq).catch((error, caught) => {
        if(error.status === 403) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']); 
        } else if(error.status === 400) {
            console.log('Error status 400');
        }
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }) as any;
```

and I get the following Error when I load the application initially:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
at http.js:168
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at HttpHeaders.lazyInit (http.js:156)
at HttpHeaders.init (http.js:277)
at HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:379)
at Observable._subscribe (http.js:2376)
at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
at CatchOperator.call (catchError.js:16)
at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:23)
```

Does anyony know why and how to prevent this error?

Comment: Is there any other code.. this seems quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this, because you can't get property status from the error response object it will be `error.error.status`

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      ...
      return next.handle(authReq).catch((error, caught) => {
        if(error.error.status === 403) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']); 
        } else if(error.error.status === 400) { 
            console.log('Error status 400');
        }
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }) as any;
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case:

```
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const token = this.getTokenFromLocalStorage();

    const headers = new HttpHeaders(
      {
        'Token': token ? token : '', // validate that this not be null!
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    );

    const REQ_INTERCEPT = req.clone({
      headers: headers
    });

    return next.handle(REQ_INTERCEPT).pipe();

  }
```

validate that token not be null!